# Access 2013 Query to find Transactions Not Like values in another table where fields may have text similar to each other

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access Table **[Transactions]** with a **![Description]** field and a **![Evaluation]** field.

Within **![Evaluation]** I want to enter *"Transaction N/A"* based on two conditions:

- if the **![Description]** field `IS NULL` OR `LIKE ""` or
- if the **![Description]** field **DOES NOT** contain text anywhere in the field that is similar to values in another table called **[SubjectToReview]![Type]**, where **[Type]** is the column within the **[SubjectToReview]** table listing different strings of verbiage I'm looking for, such as "aaaa," "bbbb," "cccc" and so on.

The tricky part is that "aaaa" can be anywhere within the **![Description]** field.

```
UPDATE Transactions 
SET Transactions.Evaluated = "Transaction N/A" 
WHERE (((Transactions.TXN_DESCRIPTION) Is Null Or (Transactions.TXN_DESCRIPTION) Like "") 
  AND  ((Transactions.TXN_DESCRIPTION) Not Like "*[TransSubjectToReclamation]![CreditTransExtPymtType]*"));
```

The above is where I'm at.  Thank you in advance for your time and expertise, ...

Comment: *The above is where I'm at.* ... Please tell us what *at* is? Any errors? Or undesired results? What is wrong with query?

Comment: You say "or" but you write "AND"...

Comment: I'll either receive '0' or 'All' records in [Transactions] as the results.  Which means the SQL isn't parsing through the ![Type] field looking for the specific verbiage in the [TransSubjectToReview]![Type] Table/Field.

Comment: I do require "OR".  I want the SQL to look for records with a NULL ![Description] field or with Values from the [TransSubjectToReview]![Type] Table/Field anywhere in [Transactions]![Description] Table/Field and enter "Transaction N/A" in the [Transactions]![Evaluation] table/field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to **query** the other table, for example in a subquery:

```
UPDATE Transactions 
SET Transactions.Evaluated = "Transaction N/A" 
WHERE Transactions.TXN_DESCRIPTION Is Null Or Transactions.TXN_DESCRIPTION Like ""
   Or Not Exists (
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM TransSubjectToReclamation 
                   WHERE Transactions.TXN_DESCRIPTION Like "*" & [CreditTransExtPymtType] & "*"
                 );
```

Comment: That did it, Sub-query did the trick, thank you, much appreciated!